# Javascript: how to check if a timestamp belongs to the current day?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to know if a certain timestamp belongs to today, but I'm getting lost in Javascripts date management.

Is there any way to check if a timestampo belongs to the current day?

Comment: Convert timestamp to date and check if it matches with current date. Keep formats without time, only date (e.g. `Y-m-d`)

Comment: Instantiate two date objects: 1) from given timestamp; 2) from the now time. Then retrieve date components (Y,m,d) for each date and compare them

Answer (score 22):

Simple check 1st timestamp of both days and compare them.

```
var ts = 1564398205000;
var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var thatDay = new Date(ts).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

if(today === thatDay){
    console.log("*** Same day ***");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems nasty-ish to me however you could do something similar to:

```
function isInToday(inputDate)
{
  var today = new Date();
  if(today.setHours(0,0,0,0) == inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0){ return true; }
  else { return false; }  
}
```

This assumes you've already set your input date as a JS date. This will check if the two dates occur on the same day, and return true if so and false if not.

I'm sure someone will come along with a neater way to do this or a case where this fails but as far as I can see this should do the trick for you.

Comment: You forgot a bracket at the end of the if condition

Answer (score 2):

you can really depend on ISO date string with a substr function to compare the two strings

```
var T=1479288780873; /*assume your timestamp value*/

var theDay=new Date(T);
var today=new Date;

theDay.toISOString().substr(0,10) == today.toISOString().substr(0,10) ? console.log("same day"):null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
var day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //nb millis in a day
var todayTimestamp = new Date(year, month, day).getTime(); // Be careful month is 0 start
//OR
var todayTimestamp = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
var diff = myTimestamp - todayTimestamp;
if ( diff >= 0 && diff  <= day ) {
    console.log("timestamp is today");
else {
    console.log("timestamp is not today");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var timestamp = '2016-11-16 03:14:07.999999';

var datestamp = timestamp.substring(0, 10);

Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; 
  var dd = this.getDate();

  return [this.getFullYear(),  mm,  dd].join('-');
};

var date = new Date();
date.yyyymmdd();

console.log(String(datestamp) === String(date.yyyymmdd()));
```

Answer (score -4):

It depends what format your timestamp is in. 
But here is the most basic way to achieve this:

```
var today = new Date(year, month, day);
var timestamp = //your timestamp;

if (timestamp == timestamp){ //make sure the date formats are the same
//your code
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for, there are more methods with the javascript date reference, don't hesitate to [look it up](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).